# Using "new" with Poco library methods

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, poco-libraries

Using the Poco libraries, if I'm doing something like this:

```
MailMessage mailMessage;
mailMessage.addPart("", new FilePartSource("/path/icon.png", "image/png"),
    Poco::Net::MailMessage::CONTENT_ATTACHMENT,
    Poco::Net::MailMessage::ENCODING_BASE64);
```

Do I need to worry about deleting the "newed" FilePartSource
that's sent to the addPart method/function in MailMessage?

[Upload a file using POCO - SSL Connection Unexpectedly Closed Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773000/upload-a-file-using-poco-ssl-connection-unexpectedly-closed-exception)

I've noticed in some examples where "new" is tossed-in places that I wouldn't call typical.

Line 65-66: new StringPartSource
https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/samples/Mail/src/Mail.cpp

Line 88: new Context
https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/NetSSL_OpenSSL/samples/Mail/src/Mail.cpp

Comment: Always read the documentation to check this.  Most of the time functions will take `Poco::AutoPtr`  (which is like `std::shared_ptr`)

Comment: Yes, **MOST functions do indeed accept a pointer. My intent here is to focus on how the provided examples seem to break traditional rules of C++ "readability".

Answer (score 2):

http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.MailMessage.html#22405

> > > The **MailMessage** takes ownership of the **PartSource** and **deletes** it when
> > >       it is no longer needed.