# Upload to Azure Blob using SAS and REST

Tags: rest, azure, blob, poco

I'm having trouble writing to an Azure Block Blob from C++ using a SAS (Shared Access Signature). I'm using the Blob REST API and Poco. The HTTP request returns error 404 (resource does not exist), but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I generate the SAS on the server in C# like this (seems to work fine):

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("my-blob");
container.CreateIfNotExists();
SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(40);
sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List;
string sasContainerToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, container.Uri + sasContainerToken);
```

In the Azure portal I can indeed see the Blob container being created as expected. I receive this SAS in C++ using an HTTP request. What I get looks like this (some names and signature replaced for security reasons):

https://myname.blob.core.windows.net/my-blob?sv=2012-02-12&se=2016-06-07T11%3A13%3A19Z&sr=c&sp=wl&sig=%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Then I try to create the file using Poco and the Blob REST API. That looks like this:

```
std::string cloudUrl = sasURI + "&restype=container";
std::string fileName = "fname.ext";
Poco::URI* uri = new Poco::URI(cloudUrl.c_str());
std::string* path = new std::string(uri->getPathAndQuery());
Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession* session = new Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession(uri->getHost(), uri->getPort());
std::string method = Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_PUT;
Poco::Net::HTTPRequest* request = new Poco::Net::HTTPRequest(method, *path, Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
request->add("x-ms-blob-content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
request->add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
request->add("x-ms-meta-m1", "v1");
request->add("x-ms-meta-m2", "v2");
Poco::Net::HTTPResponse* httpResponse = new Poco::Net::HTTPResponse();
int fileContent = 42;
request->setContentLength(sizeof(int));
request->setKeepAlive(true);
std::ostream& outputStream = session->sendRequest(*request);
outputStream << fileContent;
std::istream &is = session->receiveResponse(*httpResponse);
Poco::Net::HTTPResponse::HTTPStatus status = httpResponse->getStatus();
std::ostringstream outString;
Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(is, outString);
if (status != Poco::Net::HTTPResponse::HTTP_OK)
{
    Logger::log("Connection failed\nstatus:", status, "\nreason:", httpResponse->getReason(), "\nreasonForStatus:", httpResponse->getReasonForStatus(status), "\nresponseContent:", outString.str());
}
```

I've looked up [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/azure/dd179451.aspx) how the REST API works. I found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx) that when using a SAS I don't need to do regular authentication.

What am I doing wrong here? Why am I getting error 404?

Comment: [tag:sas] is not the SAS you are looking for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally figured out what was going wrong here. :)

There were two problems in the above code. The first is that the filename needed to be inserted into the URL, as Gaurav Mantri explained. This does the trick:

```
int indexOfQuestionMark = cloudUrl.find('?');
cloudUrl = cloudUrl.substr(0, indexOfQuestionMark) + "/" + fileName + cloudUrl.substr(indexOfQuestionMark);
```

The other problem is that I wasn't uploading enough bytes. `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes while pushing 42 into a stream turns it into characters, making it only 2 bytes. The server then keeps waiting for the remaining 2 bytes. That makes this the correct line in the example code above:

```
request->setContentLength(2);
```

Also, it works without these three lines so I suppose they're not needed:

```
request->add("x-ms-blob-content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
request->add("x-ms-meta-m1", "v1");
request->add("x-ms-meta-m2", "v2");
```

Similarly, adding this doesn't seem needed: `"&restype=container"`.

Finally, for writing the `SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List` rights aren't needed so those can be left out in SAS generation on the server side.

Answer (score 3):

I believe most of your code is correct, all you need to do is insert the file name in your SAS URL.

Now that I have seen this question more carefully, this is what is happening:

You're creating a SAS on a blob container (`my-blob`) and using this SAS to upload a file (let's call it `fname.ext`). However you're not including the file name in the SAS URL so Azure Storage Service is assuming that you're trying to upload a file called `my-blob` in a `$root` container so on the service side when Azure Blob Service tries to validate the SAS, it validates it against `$root` container. Because you created the SAS for `my-blob` container and Azure Service is using `$root` container, the SAS does not match and that's why you're getting 403 error.

What you need to do is insert the file name in your SAS URL. So your SAS URL (or Request URL) would be something like (notice that I added `fname.ext` there):

> https://myname.blob.core.windows.net/my-blob/**fname.ext**?sv=2012-02-12&se=2016-06-07T11%3A13%3A19Z&sr=c&sp=wl&sig=%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Also, you don't need the following two lines of code:

```
request->add("x-ms-version", "2015-02-21");
request->add("x-ms-date", "2016-06-07");
```

As these are not really needed when using SAS.

Comment: If I do that the line `session->receiveResponse(*httpResponse);` hangs for half a minute or so and then `SSLConnectionUnexpectedlyClosedException` is thrown. I also don't see the file appearing in the blob on the Azure portal. I tried both with and without the version and date lines. Your explanation is similar to what Gaurav Mantri posted in a comment to his own answer, but he suggests adding `"&comp=list&restype=container"` to the SAS instead, which gave a different error. I couldn't find any documentation on what values `comp` and `restype` can have in this.

Comment: Actually I provided both answers :). You don't need to do "comp=list..." thing as it is for listing blobs and you're trying to upload a blob. Can you try doing an HTTP request? Just change "https" to "http" in you request URL.

Comment: Also please see this thread for the exception you're getting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773000/upload-a-file-using-poco-ssl-connection-unexpectedly-closed-exception

Comment: If I change "https" to "http" Poco throws an exception. If I also change `HTTPSClientSession` to `HTTPClientSession` it still throws an exception.

Comment: I'm still getting the issue that if I add the filename to the URL Poco's receiveResponse() function hangs for half a minute and then times out. That's with the updated code of the question, only a few lines added to insert the filename.

Comment: Just figured out that the hang is because I was promising too many bytes, see the answer I've provided. Your suggestion that the filename needed to be there was correct, it just wasn't the only problem. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for your error could be the request date being too old. You're setting the request date as Midnight UTC tonight. Azure Storage allows about 15 minutes of clock skewness. Request date/time being "too old" is one of the major reasons for this 403 error (apart from incorrect account key and expired token in case of a SAS).

This is how you're setting `x-ms-date` request header.

```
request->add("x-ms-date", "2016-06-07");
```

This header's value should be formatted in the following format:

```
request->add("x-ms-date", "Sun, 11 Oct 2009 21:49:13 GMT");
```

Usually in C# world, we would do a `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R")` to get the date/time in correct format.

Please change your code accordingly and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! :) I've tried hardcoding the date for now, but that doesn't seem to solve it. I put in this date: "Tue, 7 Jun 2016 11:49:00 GMT"

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the date, please put the current time in UTC. Also, please get rid of `request->add("x-ms-version", "2015-02-21");` as it is already included in your SAS URL.

Comment: One way to diagnose the error is to read the error response stream. It should be an XML with more details about the error. Another thing I noticed is that your SAS has expired (se=2016-06-07T11:13:19Z). Please use a SAS which has not expired. Expired SAS will also result in 403 error. HTH.

Comment: I see in the documentation x-ms-version should indeed not be necessary but if I remove that I get HTTP_NOT_FOUND, which seems to suggest that this line is needed.

Comment: You first mentioned GMT, then UTC. The documentation says UTC, so I guess that's what I should use? I've tried both now and they both don't work. Also, the documentation suggests this date is not needed at all when using a SAS. I've tried removing the date altogether, but that didn't work either so I've put it back now. A related question: will Blob storage not work if the user has changed his system time? After all in that case I'd by adding the wrong date to the packet.

Comment: I checked the response stream and it seems to suggest it is trying to use normal authorisation while it should be using SAS. Not sure if that's just what it prints when SAS fails, or whether that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Here's the entire response (# for numbers I suppose I shouldn't be sharing):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:########-####-####-####-############
Time:2016-06-07T15:38:16.3306673Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was wl

2016-06-07T16:18:13Z
/####/$root

2012-02-12</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>

Comment: Aah....this explains the error. Please see my explanation for this error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038429/azure-shared-access-signature-signature-did-not-match (Please read "Long Answer" section in my answer).

Comment: That certainly brings it a step further, but I get a different error now. I've added this: `std::string cloudUrl = sasURI + "&comp=list&restype=container";` and now I get the error UnsupportedHttpVerb. I'm wondering whether the comp and restype here are correct for what I'm trying to do? I'm trying to give the user the right to create and write Blobs within a container. Or is something else the problem now?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the latest code and error?

Comment: I've updated my question with my current code, including the changes you suggested. The error I get now is different, so I do feel like I'm getting closer. Now it is "resource does not exist".

Comment: I'm still stuck on this one. I've noted though that error 404 doesn't need to mean the resource doesn't exist: Azure also gives this error if I don't have the correct rights. I tried setting a Blob file to public (Access policy = container) and then I can read it with a GET request just fine. When I switch the access policy to private I get error 404.

The code in the question is updated with what I have right now.

Comment: Turns out I needed to add the filename to the URL and also correct that I was promising too many bytes. See the answer I've added for more details. Thank you so much for your help! :)