# Authentication failure @ Azure node js generating SAS. Signature did not match. String to sign used was w

Tags: node.js, azure, blob, storage

I am trying to upload an image to Azure storage using a SAS. Here is the code I am using to generate a SAS.

```
function getWriteSAS() {
    var blobService = storage.createBlobService();
    var container = 'container-name';
    var blobSAS = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(container, mCurrentRequest.param.blobName, getSharedAccessPolicy(10));
    urlForDownloading = blobService.host.primaryHost + container + '?' + blobSAS
    mCurrentResponse.status(200).send({"SASURI" : urlForDownloading})
}

function getSharedAccessPolicy(accessTimeInMinutes) {
    var startDate = new Date();
    var expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
    expiryDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + accessTimeInMinutes);
    startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() - accessTimeInMinutes);

    var sharedAccessPolicy = {
        AccessPolicy: {
            Permissions: storage.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
            Start: startDate,
            Expiry: expiryDate
        },
    };
    return sharedAccessPolicy;
}
```

The Created URL looks some thing like this:
https://irewardchart.blob.core.windows.net/container-name?st=2016-06-16T06%3A24%3A52Z&se=2016-06-16T06%3A44%3A52Z&sp=w&sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=c%2F%2B7AtkH7zwLhzF%2B74%2FUeMeQ4eLDnWvVDMkiqSqroqc%3D

When I try to hit the URL from a browser, I am getting this result.

```
<Error>
<script/>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:2fab1644-0001-0087-7c99-c77b1a000000 Time:2016-06-16T06:36:14.5020064Z
</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>
Signature did not match. String to sign used was w 2016-06-16T06:24:52Z 2016-06-16T06:44:52Z /blob/irewardchart/$root 2015-04-05
</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please read my 2nd answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678058/upload-to-azure-blob-using-sas-and-rest/37692688#37692688. HTH.

Comment: Yeap, the file name is clearly missing.

Comment: Hi, any update now?

Answer (score 0):

According your description, the URL generated by your code, missed the pattern of blobName. Please double check the param `mCurrentRequest.param.blobName` in your application whether get the correct value.

And by the way, there are another two point you can pay attention to:

1. If your requirement is to browse the blob content in the browser, I suggestion you to use `storage.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.READ` permission, which can reduce the permission issue.
2. As the Azure-storage-node sdk provides a function which can generate the blob url with the SAS token, [getUrl()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js#L2245). So please try to the following code if you checked the `mCurrentRequest.param.blobName` has correct value but you still occurred the issue:

   ```
   ...
   var blobSAS = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(<containerName>, <blobName>, getSharedAccessPolicy(10));
   var sharedBlobService = azure.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobService.host, blobSAS);
   urlForDownloading =  blobService.getUrl(container,blobName,blobSAS)
   ...
   ```